# How to know that control is visible to user? (winforms)

Tags: winforms, user-interface, controls, visibility

How to know that control is visible to user?

Comment: Do you mean whether the user can actually see the control? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747935/c-winform-check-if-control-is-physicaly-visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Windows Form you can just check the .Visible property on the control. You can also use it to set the visibility.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of the properties available on a control can be used to both get and set the values.

Comment: this does not works at all, the visible property is often true long before the form is visible to the user