# GetChildAtPoint method is returning the wrong control

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor-position

My form hierarchy is something like this:

```
Form -> TableLayoutOne -> TableLayoutTwo -> Panel -> ListBox
```

In the MouseMove event of the ListBox, I have code like this:

```
    Point cursosPosition2 = PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
    Control crp = this.GetChildAtPoint(cursosPosition2);
    if (crp != null)
        MessageBox.Show(crp.Name);
```

The MessageBox is showing me "TableLayoutOne", but I expect it to show me "ListBox". Where in my code am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `GetChildFromPoint()` method uses the native `ChildWindowFromPointEx()` method, whose documentation states:

> Determines which, if any, of the child windows belonging to the
>   specified parent window contains the specified point. The function can
>   ignore invisible, disabled, and transparent child windows. **The search
>   is restricted to immediate child windows. Grandchildren and deeper
>   descendants are not searched.**

Note the bolded text: the method can't get what you want.

In theory you could call `GetChildFromPoint()` on the returned control until you got `null`:

```
Control crp = this.GetChildAtPoint(cursosPosition2);
Control lastCrp = crp;

while (crp != null)
{
    lastCrp = crp;
    crp = crp.GetChildAtPoint(cursorPosition2);
}
```

And then you'd know that `lastCrp` was the lowest descendant at that position.

Comment: Dang! Thanks for info...do you have other thoughts on how to get it? maybe reading Cursor location and checking if it is inside the location of ListBox?

Comment: See my update; you can keep calling `GetChildAtPoint()` on the returned control to go deeper in the hierarchy. You're free to check the type of control at each stage, too, so you could bail out if you found what you were looking for.

Comment: the `crp = crp.GetChildAtPoint(cursorPosition2)` is written twice which is not so beautiful, also Invisible controls are not excluded. see my post

Comment: Better integrate the next answer that uses GetChildAtPointSkip.Invisible | GetChildAtPointSkip.Transparent

Answer (score 4):

a better code can be written as following:

```
Public Control FindControlAtScreenPosition(Form form, Point p)
{
    if (!form.Bounds.Contains(p)) return null; //not inside the form
    Control c = form, c1 = null;
    while (c != null)
    {
        c1 = c;
        c = c.GetChildAtPoint(c.PointToClient(p), GetChildAtPointSkip.Invisible | GetChildAtPointSkip.Transparent); //,GetChildAtPointSkip.Invisible
    }
    return c1;
}
```

The usage is as here:

```
Control c = FindControlAtScreenPosition(this, Cursor.Position);
```